# Bound Mismatch error when trying to implement comparable interface on generic class

Tags: java, generics

I'm making a custom PriorityQueue class for a homework assignment, and I've run into a roadblock. I can't figure out how to fix this Bound Mismatch error I get in Eclipse; It won't let me try to compile as it says:

> Bound mismatch: The type `K` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<K extends Comparable<K>>` of the type `Entry<K,V>`

PriorityQueue.java:

```
  public class PriorityQueue<K,V> {

    private Entry<K,V> _head;
    private Entry<K,V> _tail;
    private int _size;

    public PriorityQueue() {
      this._head = null;
      this._tail = null;
      this._size = 0;
    }

    public int size() {
      return _size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
      return (size() == 0);
    }

    public Entry<K,V> min() {
      if (_head == null) {
        return null;
      }
      Entry<K,V> current = _head;
      Entry<K,V> min = _head;;

      while (current != null) {
        if (current.compareTo(min) < 0) {
          min = current;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
      }
      return min;
    }

    public Entry<K,V> insert(K k, V x) {
      Entry<K,V> temp = new Entry<K,V>(k,x);
      if (_tail == null) {
        _tail = temp;
        _head = temp;
      }
      else {
        _tail.setNext(temp);
        temp.setPrev(_tail);
        _tail = temp;
      }
      return temp;
    }

    public Entry<K,V> removeMin() {
      Entry<K,V> smallest = min();
      smallest.getPrev().setNext(smallest.getNext());
      smallest.getNext().setPrev(smallest.getPrev());

      return smallest;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      PriorityQueue<Integer, Integer> pq = 
          new PriorityQueue<Integer, Integer>();

      pq.insert(4, 2);
      pq.insert(5, 1);
      pq.insert(1, 5);

      System.out.println(pq.min().toString());
    }
  }
```

Entry.java:

```
public class Entry<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Comparable<Entry<K,V>> {

  private V _value;
  private K _key;
  private Entry<K,V> _prev;
  private Entry<K,V> _next;

  public Entry(K key, V value) {
    this._value = value;
    this._key = key;
    this._prev = null;
    this._next = null;
  }

  public V getValue() {
    return this._value;
  }

  public K getKey() {
    return this._key;
  }

  public Entry<K,V> getNext() {
    return _next;
  }

  public void setNext(Entry<K,V> link) {
    this._next = link;
  }

  public Entry<K,V> getPrev() {
    return _prev;
  }

  public void setPrev(Entry<K,V> link) {
    this._prev = link;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "" + this.getValue();
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Entry<K,V> o) {
    if (o instanceof Entry<?,?>) {
      return this.getKey().compareTo(o.getKey());
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Objects are not comparable.");
  }


}
```

Comment: for best results, use `K extends Comparable<? super K>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make K extends `Comparable` too for `PriorityQueue`:

```
public class PriorityQueue<K extends Comparable<K>,V> {
```

Indeed, the generic type K will be used for `Entry<K,V>`, and Entry has the constraint that it must extends (actually implements) `Comparable<K>`. You have to tell the compiler that the K for PriorityQueue also fulfill this constraint, so it allows you to use `Entry<K,V>`.

If not, someone could use PriorityQueue with a K that would not extends Comparable, and the compiler would have to check all the use of K to see if there is no constraint that prevents it use.

Comment: Ah; never saw that. Thanks for the input.